# route vpn over wifi when ethernet is first priority

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, routing, wifi, ethernet

I have a very special problem and google couldn't help me so far.

I usually connect to the Internet via ethernet (en3).
For some applications etc I need a wifi connection (en1).
So my service order is set such that the ethernet is on top of the wifi connection.

Here is how my routing tables look like:

```
Internet:
Destination      Gateway           Flags     Refs    Use    Mtu   Netif Expire
default          10.208.13.254     UGSc        13      0   1500     en3
default          10.208.219.254    UGScI        2      0   1500     en1
10.208.12/23     link#5            UCS          5      0   1500     en3
```

I additionally sometimes need a VPN connection, which should connect via the wifi. But it always tries to connect through the first service in order, which is not what I want.

Here is how the routing tables look like, when ethernet is set as the first priority connection and VPN is connected:

```
Internet:
Destination      Gateway           Flags     Refs    Use    Mtu   Netif Expire
default          10.208.219.254    UGSc         8      0   1500     en1
default          10.208.13.254     UGScI        5      0   1500     en3
default          link#13           UCSI         0      0   1280   utun0
10               141.84.17.202     UGSc         0     11   1280   utun0
10.208.12/23     link#5            UCS          8      0   1500     en3
```

Can you maybe suggest me, how I can do that, in the Network Preferences or via route add ( I am really not experienced with it, but I found that a lot of help topics mention it)

additionally, I would then like to especially make the access to one website to use the VPN connection, do I need a special route-command for that too?

Comment: Please clarify how you want the connection to be chosen.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not soo familiar with internet connections, so I don't know what you mean. I want en3 to be first priority, and en1 to be second, and the VPN should use en1. when I change priorities so that en1 is first priority my VPN can connect, but then all the other traffic is also going through en1, what I don't want.